# Ошибка "'int' object is not interable" при сортировке

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, словари

Имеется код

```
out = re.findall('window._sharedData = (.*);</script>', list_html)

json_decode = json.loads(out[0])

for e in json_decode['entry_data']['ProfilePage'][0]['user']['media']['nodes']:
    likes = e['likes']['count']
    likes = sorted(likes, key=int)
    print(likes)
```

Код выдает ошибку:

```
TypeError: 'int' object in not iterable
```

Comment: Тем не менее, для решения проблемы нужно знать, что находится внутри `out`

Comment: как и сказал *andreymal*, в следующий раз лучше прикладывать данные, с которыми работаете, т.к. не всегда можно угадать в чем была ошибка

Answer (score 1):

Проблема скорее всего в:

```
likes = e['likes']['count']
```

Это подтверждается в `likes = sorted(likes, key=int)`, т.к. в `likes` будет количество, типа `int`, а не список

---

Правильно будет:

```
likes = e['likes']
```

Comment: Не стоит словарь `d` (объект для которого `d[‘count’]` работает) в int пытаться передавать.